# Blog title is not display in browser

Tags: wordpress, blogs, permalinks

My permalink settings as below

/%category%/%postname%/

if i click on my blog or post it doesn't show the title in the browser page title.Please help me to fix.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z07bc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function in your function.php file

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpse_174379_show_posts_page_wp_title' ); function wpse_174379_show_posts_page_wp_title( $title ) { if( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) {   $posts_page = get_post( get_option( 'page_for_posts') ); 
    $title = ' ' . $posts_page->post_title . ' ';
}    return $title; }
```

I think its working for you

Comment: wp-includes/function.php file

Comment: Theme_name/function.php

Comment: i am getting this issue only for post or blog

Comment: update this code in theme index.php
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
  <main id="main" class="site-main">

   <header class="entry-header">
    <?php single_post_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
   </header><!-- .entry-header -->   

   <?php get_template_part( 'loops/loop', 'blog' ); ?>

  </main><!-- #main -->
 </div>

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
<title><?php if (is_front_page() ) { bloginfo('name'); echo ' - ';  bloginfo('description'); } else {  wp_title(''); echo ' - '; bloginfo('name');  };?></title>
```